# Images Won't Load with Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I've been trying to learn React over the past few weeks, and have decided to go through the LamaDev tutorial series. Yesterday I started with the portfolio tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQjlM-8C4Ps&t=2798s) but have been stuck with trying to load images in my array.

I went ahead and built a component called 'Product' which the code can be found below. After that I followed the instructions and built the ProductList component which is suppose to show each of my products that are in my data.js file. I have gone and posted those below.

The problem I am running in to is that if I use a random img link from the internet the image gets imported into my product and show through my product list. However this is not what I am wanting to do since there are some images of my own I wanted to use.

When my Product.jsx tried to use a image I have saved in src/assets/img/ the img won't load. I tried using the require tag but it still is not working. I have also gone ahead and uploaded everything to my github page which can be found [here](https://github.com/Ransomenote/portfolioSampleProject) and used as a reference.

I'm really not sure what I've done wrong here since everything looks right, but still know the issue is falling between the keyboard and the chair.

Thanks for any help

Product.jsx

```
import "./product.css";

const Product = ({ img, link }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p">
      <div className="p-browser">
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
      </div>
      <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        <img src={img} alt="" className="p-img" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

ProductList.jsx

```
import Product from "../product/Product";
import "./productList.css";
import { products } from "../../data";

const ProductList = () => {
  return (
    <div className="pl">
      <div className="pl-texts">
        <h1 className="pl-title">Create & inspire. It's Jon</h1>
        <p className="pl-desc">
          Jon Snow is a creative portfolio that your work has been waiting for.
          Beautiful homes, stunning portfolio styles & a whole lot more awaits
          inside.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="pl-list">
        {products.map((item) => (
          // console.log(item)
          <Product key={item.id} img={item.img} link={item.link} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

data.js

```
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: require("./assets/img/theBestTestSite.jpg"),
    link: "http://google.com",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: require("./assets/img/theBestTestSite.jpg"),
    link: "http://google.com",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: require("./assets/img/theBestTestSite.jpg"),
    link: "http://google.com",
  },
];
```

Comment: try to remove the `require()` in your array.

Comment: Imported your repo into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/images-wont-load-with-array-in-react-u9x6i) and it seems to run without issue.

Comment: That very odd @DrewReese because when I run it locally the item img is returned as a require object where the `default` property is the path of the image so you either have to import the image as Jorji suggested, or use `item.img.default`. I wonder what codesandbox is doing?

Comment: @Andy ‍♂️ I was about to suggest the same solution as Jorji but noticed the image in the array, and all other images, were rendered without issue. I'm curious now as well what codesandbox is doing differently.

Comment: It seemed Jorji solution ended up working. Not really sure why it worked in codesandbox but not locally, but I guess I'll go with this. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data.js try to import images first instead of require

```js
import img1 from "./assets/img/theBestTestSite.jpg"

export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: img1,
    link: "http://google.com",
  },
  // and same for others
];
```

Comment: That seemed to have work. I was importing it wrong it would seem. I kept trying to import it as a object {img1} when I tried that way. Thanks Jorji